# signing transaction with pkcs#11 for firefox using c code

Tags: c, firefox, digital-signature, pkcs#11

How can we do transaction signing in mozilla firefox by loading PKCS#11 library to database.
after some research i found about capicom library. but the thing is this library does not support with windows7 and higher versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot use c code but you can do the same by java applets which are to be signed. Please refer http://www.nakov.com/books/signatures/Java-for-Digitally-Signing-Documents-in-Web-book-Nakov.html

Answer (score 1):

Extension [signTextJS](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/signtextjs/) does exactly what you need and can be easily modified if needed because its [source code](https://github.com/mozkeeler/signTextJS/) is available on GitHub.

Comment: my  task is to sign the web transaction done in the client side.the link you gave serves the purpose of signing text. thank you.